# How to derive arc length formula in three dimensions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

Usually textbooks show the formula in 2D and attention is given as to how the mean value theorem allows the introduction of a derivative into the equation.

Thus far I have not been able to find a formal proof of arc length in 3D.

I thought someone might have run into one on some occasion.

Comment: The derivation can be done in the same way, so maybe review how to do it in 2 dimensions first? Note that the formula should be $z'(t)^2$.

Comment: ..thank you i will correct the typo

Comment: I counted ...maybe 20 - proofs of arc length in 2D. I counted 0 in 3D. There is probably one there it's just like finding a needle in a haystack but with a little time I think I can find one.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{r}(t)=<x(t),y(t),z(t)>$

$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=<\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}> $

$d\vec{r}=<\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}> dt$

$|d\vec{r}|=\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dz}{dt})^2} dt$

$L=\int \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dz}{dt})^2} dt$

Comment: Thank you . question. Why is the dt in step 4 located outside the norm calculation. From step 3 to 4 you are taking the norm so if you do that to  both left and right shouldn't the square root extend over the end dt? ..or did I get something messed up.

Comment: $d\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r} = [(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2+(dz/dt)^2] dt^2$ So when you take the square root, you can pull it out of the radical as dt.

Comment: ah ...sorry. I follow you now.  Before I post anything again I am going to definitely have to learn to use the fonts. sorry. I can get it from here. I will need the  mean value theorm to relate a derivative to a change in y which I can do in 2D but there is a left over 1 under the square root that I need to get rid of. Thank you you got me on the right track.